# how to extract lots of gz files in windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, gzip

I have 36,348 .gz files.

I need to extract them all the same directory. In unix I would use gunzip and so forth from the shell.

How would I do it on my windows 7 machine? I can't even get winrar to open them all at once...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7-Zip can be used on the command line. You could also use [http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm) or CygWin. Try those.

Comment: the gnu version of gzip for windows worked like a charm. Thanks for the heads up.